# Split string into INT array in c

Tags: c

I got string containing numbers separated by spaces. Numbers can be single-digit, two-digit, or perhaps more-digit. Check the example.

```
"* SEARCH 2 4 5 12 34 123 207"
```

I don't know how long the string is (how many numbers it contains), so I cant initiate the array properly. The result should look like this:

```
array = {2,4,5,12,34,123,207}
```

Do you have any ideas how to perform this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Basically you have to parse your string, the [`strtol`](https://www.google.ch/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=strtol) function may be helpful. Also look into the [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) functions.

Comment: The [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function might also come in handy.

Comment: You need dynamic array: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Comment: Only fixed sized arrays can be initialized.  OP can not solve this dynamic length problem directly.  Use VLA and then assign or allocated memory and then assign or live with array size limitations.

Comment: `"* SEARCH 2 4 5 12 34 123 207"` is not a "I got string containing numbers separated by spaces.".  Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *input = "* SEARCH 2 4 5 12 34 123 207";
    int len = 0;

    sscanf(input, "%*[^0-9]%n", &len);//count not-digits(The Number isn't negative)

    char *p = input + len;
    char *start = p;
    int v, n = 0;
    while(1 == sscanf(p, "%d%n", &v, &len)){
        ++n;//count elements
        p += len;
    }
    int array[n];//or allocate by malloc(and free)
    char *endp = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        array[i] = strtol(start, &endp, 10);
        start = endp + 1;
    }
    //check print
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux Character of the non-numeric is assumed to be in the beginning from the sample. However, to change in accordance with your advice. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. It uses a temporary buffer to hold the current integer that is being processed. It also uses dynamic arrays, to deal with different lengths of the string you want to process, and expands them when necessary. Although using [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) Would be better in this situation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char message[] = "* SEARCH 2 4 5 12 34 123 207";
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int *integers = NULL;

    int buff_size = 1, buff_len = 0;
    int int_size = 1, int_len = 0;
    int ch, messlen, i, first_int = 0;

    /* creating space for dynamic arrays */
    buffer = malloc((buff_size+1) * sizeof(*buffer));
    integers = malloc(int_size * sizeof(*integers));

    /* Checking if mallocs were successful */
    if (buffer == NULL || integers == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc problem, please check\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    messlen = strlen(message);

    /* going over each character in string */
    for (ch = 0; ch < messlen; ch++) {

        /* checking for first digit that is read */
        if (isdigit(message[ch])) {
            first_int = 1;

            /* found, but is there space available? */
            if (buff_size == buff_len) {
                buff_size++;
                buffer = realloc(buffer, (2*buff_size) * sizeof(*buffer));
            }
            buffer[buff_len++] = message[ch];
            buffer[buff_len] = '\0';
        }

        /* checking for first space after first integer read */
        if (isspace(message[ch]) && first_int == 1) {
            if (int_size == int_len) {
                int_size++;
                integers = realloc(integers, (2*int_size) * sizeof(*integers));
            }
            integers[int_len] = atoi(buffer);
            int_len++;

            /* reset for next integer */
            buff_size = 1;
            buff_len = 0;
            first_int = 0;
        }

        /* for last integer found */
        if (isdigit(message[ch]) && ch == messlen-1) {
            integers[int_len] = atoi(buffer);
            int_len++;
        }
    }

    printf("Your string: %s\n", message);

    printf("\nYour integer array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < int_len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", integers[i]);
    }

    /* Being careful and always free at the end */
    /* Always a good idea */
    free(integers);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can read each character and verify if it is in range of >=48(Ascii of 0) and less than  = 57(Ascii of 9). If so is the case read them into a array Otherwise you could copy them to a temporary string and convert to int using functions like atoi()

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j=0,k,res;
    char buff[10];
    while(str[j])
    {   
        if((str[j]>='0')&&(str[j]<='9'))
        {
            k=0;
            while((str[j]!=' ')&&(str[j]!='\0'))
            {
                buff[k]=str[j++];
                k++;
            }
            buff[k]=0;
            res=atoi(buff);
            //Store this result to an array
        }
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code in answers should at least be formatted properly. Please correct. I have not (yet) downvoted the answer. BTW your code is incomplete, it doesn't compile. And what happens if the string contains 11 numbers?

Comment: @MichaelWalz The only thing left over there is storing those values into a dynamic array
By d way if a number contains 11 digits it is no more a integer(exceeds range) so whatever asked i.e is about integers only so. 
And  may I know what kind of  formatting you are talking about ?

Comment: What kind of formatting may I know ?
I am new here !

Comment: We don't do homework!

Comment: @Anjaneyulu formatting, indentation: read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style) please

Comment: "1234567890" is a valid input without overflow for a 32-bit `int`.  This code writes outside `buff[10];` with that input.

Comment: Please add comments to clarify what you're doing.